# WCF Connection Closed exception on the 256 call

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I found an interesting error, always on call 256 in an process (there can be several running at the same time, but always the 256 call from each process will fail)

We are getting Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to [uri]. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

What is can be wrong, it seems to be the client, but it is?

Could it be because any limitation in Windows 7 and Windows Server Web Edition?

Comment: In what timeframe? Within 2 minutes?

Comment: Could be in 2 minits, any limitation?, and how do I turn it of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I it is in my company's firewall.

Thanks for your help rene

Answer (score 1):

I expect the wcf and/or TCP stack to run out of connections.

have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx

and see if fiddling with the idleTimeout or MaxConnections help.

Try adding a custombinding to your config.

```
     <customBinding>
        <binding name="mynettcp">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <tcpTransport 
              maxPendingConnections="100" 
              maxPendingAccepts="10"  
              listenBacklog="100">
            <connectionPoolSettings 
               idleTimeout="00:00:00" 
               maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="0" />
          </tcpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Then in the binding attribute of your service change the value to mynettcp

Comment: I have figured out that it is 2 minits limitations. Can I somehow change this in any configuration? I expect this limitation is per process? Is it on the client or the server the configuration needs to be changed?

Comment: we ha a server that needs to do a lot of these calls. So we need to lower this idle time limit, or figure out a way to reuse the connections.

Comment: I'm rusty on my wcf but I tried to produce a custombinding that might work for you

Comment: and if we are using HttpTransportBinding? I cant find any :(